# How do ensure that every WHEN clause in a Bigquery CASE Statement is tested iteratively before executing ELSE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

I have a `CASE` statement in my SQL which contains 4 `WHEN` clauses in it. For some reason if the first `WHEN` clause does not meet the condition it immediately executes the `ELSE` part before checking if the second, third and fourth `WHEN` clause do or do not meet the condition. I need my `CASE` statement to go through a process of elimination before executing the `ELSE`.

The CASE statement looks like this

```
SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN (st.br_cde = bsv.br_cde AND st.sku_cde = bsv.sku_cde AND st.skuprc_cost = 0) THEN bsv.skul_cost
      WHEN (b.ctry_cde = csv.ctry_cde
    AND st.sku_cde = csv.sku_cde
    AND st.skuprc_cost = 0) THEN csv.skul_cost
      WHEN (st.sku_cde = gsv.sku_cde AND st.skuprc_cost = 0) THEN gsv.skul_cost
      WHEN (bsv.skul_cost IS NULL
    AND csv.skul_cost IS NULL
    AND gsv.skul_cost IS NULL) THEN 0
    ELSE
    st.skuprc_cost
  END
    AS skuprc_cost
```

How do I structure this so that it iteratively tests each `WHEN` clause.

Comment: `case` _expression_.

Comment: It does fall through. Your cases are clearly just not matching. I suspect you're comparing null values. And not to nitpick about words but I believe you mean "successively" or "consecutively" rather than "iteratively".

Comment: no , what you claimed is not true , for sure all the cases will be examined one-by-ne until the one is true otherwise the else will be executed

Comment: @shawnt00 the table I am performing this to does not have the ctry_cde column. `b` is the alias given to the table left joined to this table. That's where ctry_cde is located. Also when I remove the first `WHEN` it works as expected. So I know that second WHEN does work correctly

Comment: @eshirvana that is what I expected. I've written other CASE statements with multiple WHEN clauses and it seems to work correctly, but for this one it is not doing it. So I'm not entirely sure what is going on exactly

Comment: look at the logic you have in your cases , there are multiple `and` condition , so it wonn't be true unless all those conditions are true

Comment: Oh I know that. You see the second `WHEN`? I started seeing the problem when one of my records did not meet the first `WHEN` clause with all it's `AND` conditions, but it met the second `WHEN` clauses `AND` conditions, yet it did not give the correct value. It instead outputted 0, which is specified in the `ELSE`

Comment: @shawnt00 might be on to something regarding the ctry_cde. I may have to recreate this table first within a CTE and include the ctry_cde column first then perform this CASE logic outside of that CTE and drop the column in the final SQL as it's not part of it's SCHEMA. I am dreading that, but it may be the only solution

Comment: A lot of the logic seems to run in parallel which is why I initially thought perhaps that was the wrong table. I don't know if that was a useful idea. Have you tried outputting the branch number instead of the cost column to verify it's actually doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: Did you check the values of the fields of the first “when”?. The syntax of the case statement looks correct. Is an information error.